# Symfony2 - extending entities, abstract entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 entities with the same fields - parent, children, order. Actually it is a mechanism and this 3 fields not applicable to content of this entity - like name, title, category etc.

I want to set this fields to one place, one class and I'm considering where should I put it. Should it be an abstract class? Or should I make a trait?

I also can use **ORM\Discriminator** mechanism, but I think this is for something else, not for that what I want to do.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your use case? Currently, it is not clear how related the entities are that should share common behavior.

Comment: They aren't related. It's two separated entities, which have the same fields.

Comment: Better make 2 normal Entities .. There are often identical attributes but the idea is to have as much as its possible independent Entitties .. If you want how ever to do something Traits are better option. (for example Dates Trait can store created/updated/published date time fields, which can be used in different types of entities..) and you can use it in absolutely different Entites where you want..

Comment: In addition to previous comment. Think about traits if the classes you want to extend with them do not belong to the same kind of data. Like for example manager and user. Both they have email, name, etc. And depending on purpose the might be designed hierarchically. But if it's Price and Order you can use Trait (CreatedAwareTrait for example) because they are absolutely different kinds of data.

Comment: And do not use an abstract class as a base class for your entities if you don't plan to have any abstract methods in it.

Comment: Actually I can do it by using `@MappedSuperclass`, but I've came to conclusion - It's not necessary, I'll do it normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i would make an abstract class with doctrines @MappedSuperClass annotation and shared fields and the entities extend them

here is an example with a shared created_at field

```
namespace Your\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;



/**
 * Abstract base class to be extended by my entity classes with same fields
 *
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;


    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return AbstractEntity
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

your entities both extend this class like:

```
class YourEntityClass extends AbstractEntity
{
```

in YourEntityClass the $id property must be "protected"

Comment: and don't forget about manual `@MappedSuperclass`, https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.5/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Answer (score 2):

I had that issue some time ago. I also wanted to have nice abstraction for entities (or value objects, whatever) just to be a little lazy. But It is not the good way IMHO.

What if name from one entity has to have other length than the other? What if you want to add new field, add it to one entity, and some time later you wanted it in the other entity, but you forget to move it to abstraction?

I think entity is such autonomic thing that it is pointless and confusing to move some part of it to the abstraction.

Remember about [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.