# How should Symfony projects implement UML2 class interfaces in its entity classes?

Tags: doctrine-orm, interface, uml, symfony

After reading around how to build UML class diagrams and using [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), I've tried putting together a UML class diagram I'm happy with for a new Symfony project I'm going to start.

However, with the interfaces I've defined - for example:

[image: example UML class diagram with Interface]

I'm unclear if/how they should be implemented as Symfony abstract entities. From what I've read there seems to be conflicting opinions:

1. [Symfony Docs: How to Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) , however this seems to just be for when accessing abstract classes from other bundles?
2. [Questions such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782386/symfony2-extending-entities-abstract-entity#33784105) where people advise against using abstract classes and to isntead create 'normal' entities (ie Professor and Student) - although isn't this then disregarding the benefits of SOLID?

Comment: I think, this is rubbish (sorry for the harsh words). Person is no interface. It's a simple (maybe abstract) class. An interface needs methods, not attributes since it offers functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that's helpful. It was just a basic diagram to get the idea across but in my actual case i do have methods in 'Person' too. So is it right to say that an interface would be an "abstract class + methods"?

Comment: I guess you can say that :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [Inheritance Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) section of the Doctrine documentation... It allows you to have an abstract "Person" class and then extend it to make it a "Student" or a "Teacher" there are a couple of different ways you can pull this off... the simplest of which is the `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance, which uses a "discriminator" in the database to know what type of an entity it is.

Comment: Thank you - the mapped superclass looks correct with regard to the data model - however as @Thomas Kilian pointed out, my choice of image was not the best as it does not show any methods (which I need to deal with). Should these methods be specified in a new file `person.php` which specifies my abstract class - and then have the actual entities (eg Professor & Student) as distinct files eg `professor.php` using `class Professor extends Person{...}`

Comment: @Bendy that's correct... the Person Class is an Abstract classs... it cannot be instantiated ... so you always have to extend it so you can use it... so you are going to have 3 files... Person.php Professor.php and Student.php...

Answer (score 1):

Your classes seem to represent ordinary (business) object types as defined in a UML class diagram representing a data model for an app. In your example, it's natural to consider the class hierarchy formed by the root class `Person` with two subclasses `Professor` and `Student` in the data model. Now, when you have to implement such a data model (with subclasses and/or relationships/associations between classes) in some framework, the question is how to define corresponding model classes (also called "entity classes"), and the answer depends on the framework's support for these concepts.

Generally, when you have to deal with a class hierarchy in your app, and your OO framework supports inheritance/specialization between model/entity classes, then the main issues is how to map the class hierarchy to a set of tables in the underlying SQL DBMS as part of the Object-Relational Mapping (ORM).

In the data model, you wouldn't use interfaces, since they are an OO programming concept, and not a data semantics concept. However, in the data model you could define Person to be an abstract class, which implies that it does not have any direct instance and its only purpose is to define features (properties, methods and constraints) that are inherited by subclasses. Btw, this assumption/decision would imply that there are no other instances of `Person`, except students and professors.

If your framework (e.g., *Symfony*) does not support inheritance from abstract classes, but some form of interfaces, then you may use an interface to get something like an abstract class defining abstract methods only. An interface `Person` would define getters/setters for `firstname` and `lastName`.

Since in many cases, and also in the case of your simple example, the given class hierarchy is pretty simple, it's preferable to eliminate the sublcass relationships and reduce the conceptual class hierarchy of the data model to a plain set of classes using the [class hierarchy merge design pattern](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JavaJpaJsf/book/ch17s05.html). This avoids all the overhead that comes with defining interfaces and maintaining the relationships between them and the classes that implement them. It's equivalent to keeping the class hierarchy in your model/entity classes and using the Single-Table-Inheritance ORM pattern.