# Doctrine abstract with entities with same column names

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a symfony project that uses doctrine and I am going insane. I have an abstract entity called hardware and then I have hub entity and computer entity that extends hardware.

My issue is that they all have barcode and partnumber columns. I started with just hub and computer but then I realized that I am duplicating so I have an abstract hardware entity as a base class.

I am trying to get the hub barcode and partnumber in the view but I have xdebug and I can see that the hub entity does not have a value for either column.

To see if I am looking in the wrong place I added a partnumber and barcode in the db for hub and computer (and even hardware) but it still stays blank.

Any help?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782386/symfony2-extending-entities-abstract-entity

Comment: I use abstract base entities that share fields with extended entities all the time (think of things like `createdAt` and `updatedAt` definitions).  I never have a problem.  Without seeing any code it's nearly impossible to figure out what's going wrong.